# KRunner file search out of date, despite baloosearch giving correct results

Tags: kde, search-indexing

When searching for files with KDE's KRunner, I am getting outdated results. Calling `baloosearch` directly gives the expected results, which is strange, since KRunner should be using just that.

---

For instance, when I renamed

```
From:  "obscure_filename_AUTHOR.pdf"
To:    "YEAR - AUTHOR - TITLE.pdf"
```

executing `baloosearch AUTHOR` will yield the new filename, but typing `AUTHOR` into KRunner still shows `obscure_filename_AUTHOR.pdf` only -- and trying to open it yields the expected "file not found" error.

Similar issues occur with file creation (KRunner doesn't find the file) and deletions (KRunner still finds the file), despite `baloosearch` showing, that the index is updated.

My issue is similar to what is described in the reddit post [KRunner: Force reindex of available files](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/aeup21/krunner_force_reindex_of_available_files/). However, in my case the solution doesn't apply, since the baloo index isn't outdated; Only the results in KRunner are.

In that post, the problem was solved by forcing a reindexing of baloo, but in my case the baloo index *is* already up to date, with `baloosearch` giving the expected result.

For testing I forced a reset by executing

```
balooctl stop
sleep 10
rm $HOME/.local/share/baloo/index
rm $HOME/.local/share/baloo/index-lock
sleep 10
balooctl start
```

Is there some kind of cache in KRunner, that may be out of date?

Comment: I have the same problem: baloosearch works as expected, however krunner doesn't find the file